# Umbraco uSync - importing does not show element causing issue

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

uSync import error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Extending Umbraco And Using The API
Umbraco 7
We are currently using uSync but now have an environment where we get this below error in the logs when attempting an import

My question is - how can I trace WHICH element is causing this issue during the import? The debugging does not show which element is being processed when the error occurs

Many thanks

> 2019-03-04 11:09:34,497 [P1716/D7/T160] ERROR
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.Controllers.uSyncApiController - Unhandled
>   controller exception occurred System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object. at
>   Jumoo.uSync.Core.Serializers.ContentTypeBaseSerializer1.DeserializeBase(IContentTypeBase
>   item, XElement info)    at
>   Jumoo.uSync.Core.Serializers.ContentTypeSerializer.DeserializeCore(XElement
>   node)    at
>   Jumoo.uSync.Core.Serializers.SyncBaseSerializer1.DeSerialize(XElement
>   node, Boolean forceUpdate) at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.Handlers.ContentTypeHandler.Import(String
>   filePath, Boolean force) at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.Handlers.uSyncBaseHandler1.ImportFolder(String 
>   folder, Boolean force, Dictionary2 updates) at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.Handlers.uSyncBaseHandler1.ImportFolder(String 
>   folder, Boolean force, Dictionary2 updates) at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.Handlers.uSyncBaseHandler1.ImportFolder(String 
>   folder, Boolean force, Dictionary2 updates) at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.Handlers.uSyncBaseHandler1.ImportFolder(String 
>   folder, Boolean force, Dictionary2 updates) at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.Handlers.uSyncBaseHandler1.ImportAll(String
>   folder, Boolean force)    at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.uSyncBackOfficeContext.Import(IEnumerable1
>   syncHandlers, String folder, Boolean checkConfig, Boolean force,
>   String groupName) at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.uSyncBackOfficeContext.Import(String groupName,
>   String folder, Boolean force) at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.uSyncBackOfficeContext.ImportAll(String folder,
>   Boolean force) at
>   Jumoo.uSync.BackOffice.Controllers.uSyncApiController.Import(Boolean
>   force)

Comment: I've used uSync quite extensively and I found out it doesn't clean up after itself. Check your solution, before publishing to see if there are missing files in the uSync folders (aka files in there with a small triangle on the top left). I found out that deleting things from uSync didn't remove the folder and I got similar errors. It's manual, but eh.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure Kev who maintains uSync is on here much. I'd raise an issue on the Github repo for uSync here: https://github.com/KevinJump/uSync/issues and Kev will usually get back to you pretty quickly.

It's possibly something to do with a missing DataType or something though.

You can try setting the logger to log more detailed information for uSync which might give you more information to go on. To do this, add the following:

```
<logger name="Jumoo.uSync"><level value="Debug" /></logger>
```

to the `config/log4net.config` file on your site. this should cause uSync to log more information to the `/App_Data/umbracoTraceLog.txt` file which might give you more useful information!

Hope that helps!

Comment: No need to create an issue immediately. in our.umbraco.com kevin is pretty active and responds to forums. He has responded quite a few times to me.